# Template literals with html tags

Tags: javascript, string, template-literals

Hei,
I am working with template literals and I have like this:

```js
const literal = `
      <h4>HTML</h4>
      <h2>firstTitle}</h2> 
...
`

blackBoard.innerHTML = literal;
```

But I also want that it renders the HTML tags? The template is quite long, so I am wondering if there is even a better approach to show the template and the tags itself.

Comment: If you want to render the tags as text, don't assign to `.innerHTML` but to `.textContent`.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, I saw the textcontent, but the name tricked me as I thought it only shows up the text content :) . And in case that I want only some tags to show as tags and others don't, it's better to make more than one template literal or there is another better approach?

Comment: If you want to show them, they're not tags but text. Use HTML entities for their characters: `&lt;h4&gt;HTML&lt;/h4&gt;`

Comment: Like a punch in the nose :) ...You are so right. Yes, makes total sense now. Thank you very much @Bergi